# configure wamp apache for production environment

Tags: php, html, apache, wamp

I have a web app am developing in-house and testing with wamp and it gives me all the normal results. PHP functions working well, errors reporting and responding when corrected. However, when I moved the site to a remote web hosting service, I get a Server 500 error as the first page tries to load. All the pages that have performed brilliantly in the local wamp setting suddenly reported errors with the same code.

I am wondering if there's something wrong in my wamp setting that makes it behave differently from the remote hosting sites. I have loaded the site on two linux hosting sites now with the same Serve 500 errors.

Please, I need help on how to tune my wamp for standard web operations so that I'd be sure to get the same results I get locally when I run it remotely.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an `.htaccess` file? If it points to invalid paths or you do stuff that the remote server does not support then you will usually get a 500 server error.

Comment: Yes, I have an htaccess file but contains only a DirectoryIndex directive because my first file is a login.php rather than an index.html or index.php  Thanks

Comment: Create a "Virtual Host" for each of your sites, especially if you want to eventually move them to a hosted server. [See here for help with configuring a VHOST and why you should do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly
I have followed the steps referred religiously and the new defined site folder or virtual host, keeps redirecting me to the wampserver homepage.
See my VirtualHost definition

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@globalbday
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/globalbday"
    ServerName globalbday
    ServerAlias globalbday
    ErrorLog "logs/globalbday"
    CustomLog "logs/globalbday" common
 <Directory "c:/wamp/www/globalbday">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require local
  DirectoryIndex index.php index.html login.php
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>